# Sorting descending in a Datagridview that reads from XML file?

Tags: xml, sorting, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView that reads from a xml file. The code looks like this :

```
        ds.ReadXml("highscore.xml");

        poengListe.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

The xml file holds user/players name and score. At the moment when I display the xml in the DVG it displays the users in the order they entered the high score list, but I want it to be decending with the highest score on the top and the rest below it. Any idea how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = ... whatever column score is in
poengListe.Sort(poengListe.Columns[i], ListSortDirection.Descending)
```

Comment: You might want to explain better your answer

Comment: see msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z.aspx for documentation

Comment: @a_schimpf : That seem to work, but when the number is doubledigit it put it self lower on the table.  Angelina 5
 Test  2
 Test 13 <--- here. It seems to only use the first digit.
 Jada 1
 Marius 0

Comment: i have a feeling its treating the values in that column as strings, thus only sorting by the first character. make sure the score column is a numeric type.